# Kernel and stabilizer of a group $G$ acting on a nonempty subset $A$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $A$ be a nonempty set. Consider $G$ acting on $A$ defined by the left group action $g \cdot a$, $g \in G$ and $a \in A$.

My question is that is the kernel of the group action:
$$K = \{g\in G\mid  g \cdot a = a \forall a\in A\},$$
a subgroup of the stabilizer of $s \in G:$
$$G_s = \{ g\in G \mid g \cdot s = s \}?$$

It seems like $K \leq G_s$ but I am currently having doubts.

My Proof:

If $x \in K$ then $x \cdot a = a$ for all $a \in A$. By the definition of the stabilizer $x \in G_s$, hence $K \subseteq G_s$ and $K$ and $G_s$ are subgroups of $G$, then $K \leq G_s \leq G$.

Comment: $K$ is the intersection of all stabilizers of elements of $A$. In particular, it is a subgroup of each stabilizer.

Comment: I knew about this fact, but thank you for clearing this up.

Comment: "a subgroup of the stabilizer of $s \in G:$" rather of $s\in A.$

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been answered in the comments.

Comment: What in your proof are having doubts about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$K = \{g\in G\mid  g \cdot s = s \ \ \forall s\in A\}=\{g\in G\mid  g \in G_s \ \ \forall s\in A\}=\{g\in G\mid  g \in \bigcap_{s \in A} G_s\}=\bigcap_{s \in A} G_s$$
Hence, $K< G_s \ \ \forall s \in A$.

Your proof is also fine.